# Are widgets meant to be used outside of sidebars?

Tags: widgets, sidebar

Are widgets meant to be used outside of sidebars?

My case: I have this html block which I want to use every time I display a post with category of "Story". I was going to make a widget to reduce duplicate code. Is there a better way to apply this html block to every displaying of a "Story" post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the category is `Story`, then make a template file, and name it as `category-story.php` (make sure the slug is 'story'). Put your code in this file. WordPress will automatically display the posts from `Story` category using this template. ([More about category templates here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates#What_Template_File_is_Used.3F)). And yes, you can use widgets outside of the sidebar, [read how](http://wpmu.org/how-to-widgetize-a-page-post-header-or-any-other-template-in-wordpress/).

Answer (score 1):

I frequently use widgets outside sidebars. It's a fantastic way to make editing content in WordPress easier, however in your situation you may wish to use a file named 'category-story.php' or use the [is_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category) conditional tag to display content when a given category is viewed.

Answer (score 1):

Widgets are just placeholders with enhanced functionality. I build a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/magic-widgets/) once to add widgets to the head and footer sections of an HTML document.
I’d say it depends on your needs: If you need some configuration use a widget. Otherwise shortcodes or special templates may do the same job.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one common use is the Widgetized Footer. The typical ones enable one to put three or four columns in the footer which you populate via widgets.